# Oracle script not outputting clearly

Tags: sql, oracle, output

Im having trouble making my script output come across as 1 full block instead of just wrapping and making a new line and it is really throwing me off. I have included a screenshot of what it looks like. If there is anyone that can help me figure out how to make it display in one line that would be wonderful!

Thank you!

https://gyazo.com/a2f28a3c58a76252bd56335213248e27

Comment: What tool are you using? SQL*Plus?

Comment: I think I need the commands to increase line size and page size

Answer (score 3):

You can modify your output format in different ways; for example, starting from here:

```
SQL> select table_name, owner, tablespace_name, cluster_name from dba_tables where rownum < 2;

TABLE_NAME                     OWNER
------------------------------ ------------------------------
TABLESPACE_NAME                CLUSTER_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
ICOL$                          SYS
SYSTEM                         C_OBJ#
```

You can fix the linesize:

```
SQL> set linesize 1000
SQL> select table_name, owner, tablespace_name, cluster_name from dba_tables where rownum < 2;

TABLE_NAME                     OWNER                          TABLESPACE_NAME                CLUSTER_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
ICOL$                          SYS                            SYSTEM                         C_OBJ#
```

or even decide a format for each column:

```
SQL> column table_name format a10
SQL> select table_name, owner, tablespace_name, cluster_name from dba_tables where rownum < 2;

TABLE_NAME OWNER                          TABLESPACE_NAME                CLUSTER_NAME
---------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
ICOL$      SYS                            SYSTEM                         C_OBJ#
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch6.htm#i1081036) you find more details.